# Child process php-cgi.exe finished with 0

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I start Nginx with PHP in Windows. Nginx connects to PHP with FastCGI. Everything works correctly, but sometimes `php-cgi.exe` crashes and does not work. The windows log is:

> Child process [3952 - D:\nginx\php\php-cgi.exe  -b127.0.0.1:9000 -cD:\nginx\php\php.ini ] finished with 0

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=0
set PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
and run pgp-cgi with these environment values.
```

Comment: Er… setting a `PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS` is almost certainly *not* appropriate here. It'd cause PHP to exit after 5000 requests, causing problems very similar to what the question is complaining about!

Comment: 1) it creates awareness about this value, 2) it makes the problem owner look into this issue to exclude it from being the problem source. Phpcgi should always exit after x number of requests, wrappers should be aware of this and simply loop back.